# auto start mysql

Tags: linux, mysql

how can i make mysql start automatically on linux?

Comment: You should atl east specify which linux distribution you're using.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the complete steps to make sure mysql is started at boot time on RHEL4.  They need to be run with root permission.

```
chkconfig --list mysqld
```

Unless you installed mysqld in a non-default way, this should show that mysqld is set to start at run levels 3,4 and 5:

```
mysqld          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

If this isn't the case, set up the correct run levels.  If you didn't get any output from the previous command:

```
chkconfig --add mysqld
```

Then:

```
chkconfig --level 345 mysqld on
```

Finally, use chkconfig --list again to make sure you're set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on your linux distribution. On Debian/Ubuntu something like this would work:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed mysql from the package manager it should set it up to start by default.

Answer (score 0):

And on a RHEL derivate, it'll work like this:

```
sudo /sbin/chkconfig mysqld on
```